# Echo not displaying, or adding ID, but shows up in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I set up a PHP database that worked perfectly on my local server. Then, when I went to put it online through my hosting site, Site5, I was getting these kinds of errors: "Cannot modify header information – headers already sent by...". So I changed the PHP file on Site5  to have output buffering turned on. Now, I am not getting an error, however, whenever I input data, it doesn't echo it back - however, it does show up in the database in phpMyAdmin (but without an ID).

Any ideas as to why it isn't echoing back and why it's new data isn't getting an ID?

Here it is live (and broken):
http://hjaramillo.com/tell_me/index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>A Message For You</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link href="css/media.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<?php 
 ob_start();
 //error_reporting(0);
 require 'db/connect.php'; 
 require 'functions/security.php';
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

 $records = array();

 if(!empty($_POST)){


 if(isset($_POST['first_name'],$_POST['location'],$_POST['message'])) {

$first_name = trim($_POST['first_name']);
$location   = trim($_POST['location']);
$message    = trim($_POST['message']);

if(!empty($first_name) && !empty($location) && !empty($message)) {
  $insert = $db -> prepare("INSERT INTO message (first_name, location, message, date) VALUES (?,?,?,NOW())");
  $insert->bind_param('sss',$first_name,$location,$message);

  if($insert -> execute()){
    header ('Location: index.php');
    die();
  }
}

 }
}
if($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM message ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")) {
if($results->num_rows) {
  while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
    $records[] = $row;
   }
   $results -> free();
 }
}

?>
<?php
  if (!count($records)){
    echo 'No messages';
  } else{

?>
  <?php
  foreach($records as $r){
  ?>

<body>
  <?php
  }}
?>
<div class="form-show">
  <div class="post-icon">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/post_icon.png"/></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-background">
<div class="form-container">
<div class="form-title">
   <p>Tell someone that:</p>
</div>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
      <div class="fields msg">
        <!--<label for="message">Message</label>-->
        <textarea name="message" id="message" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="fields">
      <ul>
        <li> <label for="first_name">Name</label> </li>
        <li> <input type="text" class="s-input" name="first_name" id="first_name" autocomplete="off"> </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="fields last">
        <ul>
          <li><label for="location">Location</label></li>
          <li><input type="text" class="s-input" name="location" id="location" autocomplete="off"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Post" id="submit-button">
   </form>
  <div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="msg-container">
 <div class="msg-intro">
  <p> On <?php echo escape($r->date); ?>,</p>
  <p><span style="text-transform:capitalize;"><?php echo escape($r->first_name); ?>            </span> from 
 <span style="text-transform:capitalize;"><?php echo escape($r->location); ?></span>   wanted to tell you:</p>
  </div>
  <div class="msg-content">
    <p><?php echo escape($r->message); ?></p>
  </div>
 </div>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/application.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: you cannot place html before headers...headers must be called before any output is printed on the page

Comment: Someone earlier asked if my ID was set to AUTO INCREMENT - it wasn't. That was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Someone earlier asked if my ID was set to AUTO INCREMENT - it wasn't. That was the problem, thanks!